# Rails: Error using ActionView method sanitize in Lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to use the Sanitize method from ActionView.

The line `r_str = Helper.instance.sanitize(r_str, :tags => @@allowed_tags, :attributes => @@allowed_attribs)` is giving me the error

```
undefined method `white_list_sanitizer' for Parsers::HTML::Helper:Class
```

This is my code in `lib/parsers.rb`

```
module Parsers
  module HTML
    @@allowed_tags = %w(--snip--)
    @@allowed_attribs = %w(--snip--)

    class Helper
        include Singleton
        include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
    end

    #Use built-in santizer and the Hpricot plugin
    def self.clean(str)
      rgx = /<code>(.*?)<\/code>/ #All html within a code tag should be escaped.
      r_str = str.gsub(rgx) { |match| "<code>" + CGI.escapeHTML(match[5..-7]) + "</code>" } # TODO: test this.
      r_str = Helper.instance.sanitize(r_str, :tags => @@allowed_tags, :attributes => @@allowed_attribs)
      Hpricot(r_str)
    end

  end

  --snip-- 

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Please do not comment on the dangers of allowing user submitted HTML, I know the risks)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The proper class in rails is `HTML::Sanitizer`

Comment: I don't know why this answer was selected... none of these worked for me.

Comment: undefined method `sanitize' for HTML::Sanitizer:Class

Answer (score 3):

simply do instead of "include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper",

```
 include ActionView::Helpers
```

this above will mix in the ClassMethods from SanitizeHelper, and your code will work.

Note: I have also seen suggestions to explicitly do:

```
extend ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper::ClassMethods
```

Answer (score 0):

You need also class methods from sanitize helper

```
 class Helper
   include Singleton
   include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

   class << self
     include SanitizeHelper::ClassMethods
   end
 end
```